# How to simulate a random variable with this density?

Tags: random-variable, simulation, density-function

I need to generate random variables $R$ with this distribution function:

$$F_R(y)=\frac{1}{\mu(\lambda,\tau)}\int_{0}^{y}e^{-\lambda x^{\tau}}dx$$
where $0\lt\tau\lt 1,$ $\lambda\gt 0$ (it is like the rate of an exponential distribution), and $\mu$ is the normalizing constant.

But, I am not clear how to proceed. Is it ok if I consider the associated density; *i.e.,*

$$f_R(x)=\frac{1}{\mu}e^{-\lambda x^\tau}$$

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly $R \ge 0$ (for otherwise the integrand would not be defined when $y \lt 0$ for many such values of $\tau$).  Because the differential element is proportional to

$$f_R(r)\mathrm{d}r \propto \exp(-\lambda  r^\tau) \mathrm{d}r,$$

the variable $U = \lambda R^\tau$ has differential element proportional to

$$f_U(u)\mathrm{d}u \propto u^{1/\tau}\exp(-u) \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u},$$

exhibiting $U$ as a $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)$ variable.  (Thus, $R$ follows a [Generalized Gamma Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution).)  Consequently, you may generate $U$ according to this Gamma distribution (with many well-known efficient methods of generation) and compute

$$R = \left(\frac{U}{\lambda}\right)^{1/\tau}.$$

To illustrate, here is the histogram of $10^4$ independent realizations of $R$ computed in this manner with the `R` code below.  It is shown on a logarithmic axis for clarity, on which the density of $\log R$ implied by $f_R$ is plotted as a red curve.  The correspondence is excellent:

[image: Histogram]

This eight-year-old workstation generates five million values of $R$ per second.  You might be able to do better with a more modern one.

```
#-- Specify parameters.
lambda <- 3
tau <- 1/4

#-- Generate variates.
n <- 1e4
R <- (rgamma(n, 1/tau, 1) / lambda)^(1/tau)

#-- Plot the results and compare to the intended distribution.
hist(log(R), freq=FALSE)
curve(exp(x - lambda * exp(tau * x) - lgamma(1+1/tau) + log(lambda)/tau),
      add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
```

Comment: Could you explain to me why $U$ is $\gamma(\frac{1}{\tau})$ is clear that $$f_U(u)du\propto u^{\frac{1}{\tau}-1}exp(-u)du$$ but the limits of the gamma function are from $0$ to $\infty$, Moreover Why did you conclude that $R$ follows the Gamma generalized distribution, I have seen the distribution given in Wikipedia, but I cannot relate such distribution with $R=(\frac{U}{\lambda})^{1/\tau}$

Comment: Wikipedia isn't very clear about this, but a generalized Gamma distribution essentially is the distribution of a power of a Gamma variable--it's that simple.  If you intend $R$ to have an upper limit, that would truncate it: but then it would have a truncated generalized Gamma distribution. You could generate variates from it fairly rapidly using its quantile function.

Comment: One question, in one of the editions provided someone added "normalizing constant" to the parameter $\mu$.  Actually the idea of the computation of this Distribution comes from here: I have to generate random variables  that has the next density $$\frac{\bar{B}(x)}{\mu(B)}=\frac{1-(1-exp(-\lambda x^{\tau}))}{\mu_B}$$ in this case $\mu_B$ is the mean of the Weibull distribution. $B(x)$ is the Weibull distribution, and $\bar{B}(x)$ is the survival function.  It changes someway the answer? What do you mean with normalizing constant?