# Probability of the generalized gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution

I am trying to compute the value of $\bar F(x)=1-F(x)$ where F(X) is the generalized Gamma distribution. I found that this distribution is also called the equilibrium distribution of Weibull. Someone knows a package in R to compute this cumulative probability? or how to deal with it?

I found the argument of equilibrium distribution here page 9 https://file.scirp.org/pdf/JMF_2016082314152700.pdf. And actually worked for me I use it to generate random deviates of such density, but now I need to compute the exact value for F(x).

I also was trying to use the method suggested here

[How to simulate a random variable with this density?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349729/how-to-simulate-a-random-variable-with-this-density/349779?noredirect=1#comment659555_349779)

without success. But I think that is right, now I need to evaluate F(x) for F the equlibrium distribution of Weibull or generalized gamma. that I think that are the same thing.

Comment: Can you define the meaning of the bar over the $F$ in your question?

Comment: The common names of $\bar{F}(x)$ are [complementary cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_(tail_distribution)) or survival function.

Comment: You should find answers here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution   If not, explain what you cannot find answered there.

Answer (score 0):

This distribution is implemented in the R packages `rmutil` and `flexsurv`. Just have a look at them and be careful with the potentially different parametrizations:

http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/rmutil/html/GGamma.html

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/flexsurv.pdf